# I want to have 2 streams. Electric guitar thru Zoom g3n to powered speaker Acoustic guitar/ mic thru fender amp to powered speaker

Tags: guitar, pa

Set up also has TC electronics singer pedal which pairs with guitar.
The Acoustasonic 100 has great vocal settings and my Martin guitar sounds better than going through Zoom.
I have a 6 channel passive mixer and end of effects board a ABY SPLITTER BOX.
Powered speaker also has guitar / mic inputs

Comment: What's the question here? It sounds like you have a pretty specific idea what you want, so what's stopping you from doing it?